# Can Apache Proxy exclude root (/) while including the rest?

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874277/can-apache-reverse-proxy-exclude-certain-file-types), I've been able to set-up my development machine. Local files (ico, png, js, css, html, etc) are served directly by Apache.

There's only one glitch. I also want the document root `/index.html` to be served by Apache and not by the application server.

`ProxyPassMatch / !` does that, but then the next line

`ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/` doesn't work (obviously).

My WSGI server doesn't have a special syntax for Apache to distinguish it.

- `/this` should be passed to `http://localhost:8000/this`
- `/that` should be passed to `http://localhost:8000/that`

`ProxyPass /$1 http://localhost:8000/$1` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer changing `ProxyPassMatch / !` to `ProxyPassMatch /$ !`

The '$' means the end of the regex, so only the request ending in / will be served by Apache.

`ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/` will pass the rest of the requests to the WSGI server.

Comment: You could also reduce to just a single ProxyPassMatch ^(/.+)

Comment: @covener, Interesting. Thanks. Regex isn't my forte to be honest.

Comment: A warning: this will ignore `/`, `/example/`, `/something/else/`... anything that ends with a slash. Instead try `ProxyPassMatch ^/$ !` if you only want to ignore the root.